# How to mapreduce in this situation in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to analysis a text file
the text file's format is like this...

```
<msg time='2015-07-30T16:37:48.408+09:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='rdbms' 
msg_id='opiexe:3056:2780954927' client_id='' type='NOTIFICATION'
group='admin_ddl' level='16' host_id='TEST_DB1'
host_addr='127.0.0.1' module='sqlplus@TEST_DB1 (TNS V1-V3)' pid='24436'>
<txt>ORA-1543 signalled during: create tablespace TS_MODULE_I datafile &apos;/data001/orasvc01/NEWDB/ts_module_i_01.dbf&apos; size 20m...
</txt>
</msg>

<msg time='2015-07-30T16:39:13.173+09:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='rdbms'
client_id='' type='UNKNOWN' level='16'
host_id='TEST_DB1' host_addr='127.0.0.1' module=''
pid='23242'>
<txt>Errors in
file /logs001/orasvc01/diag/rdbms/newdb/NEWDB/trace/NEWDB_smon_23242.trc:
ORA-01116: error in opening database file 6
ORA-01110: data file 6:
&apos;/data001/orasvc01/NEWDB/ts_module_d_01.dbf&apos;
ORA-27041: unable to open file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
</txt>
</msg>
```

....

sometimes it includes 7lines but other thing inculde 10 lines.
in this situation..

I want an output like
(column[0])     (column[1])   sum of errors

2015-07-31       ora-1051         7

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file is xml. If you have entire xml as a string in each line, you would hae used straight forward map reduce. However your input is in different form. Mostly dependent on start and end tag, to get a record.

So you should use record reader, and create your own format for map reduce- XmlInputFormat. The good news is, its already created, and you have to customize it. You can search for "xmlinputformat mahout", for actual class. However even more easier way is, to see an example which uses the above format. You can find it [here](http://thinkbigdataanalytics.com/xmlinputformat-hadoop/). Once your mappers recornizes a record, and you get hold of the contents inside, the rest is straigth forward, and it depends on you which details are to be sent to output. Happy coding